# How can a 32 bytes address represent more than 32 characters?

Tags: solidity

I have just started studying solidity and coding in general, and I tend to see things like this:

[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ1q7.jpg)

I am confused as to how a "32 bytes hash" can include more than 32 characters (even after the "0x000").  I was under the impression that each byte can represent a character.  I often see references, as well, saying things like "32 bytes address (64 bytes hex address)".  But how can a 64 byte hex address be represented if it is a 32 bytes address - would you still need a byte per character?  I know this is probably a stupid/noob question, and I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One byte is the range 00000000 - 11111111 in binary, or 0x00 - 0xFF in hex. As you can see, one byte is represented in hex as a 2 character string. Therefore, a 32 byte hex string is 64 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

The 32-bit address points to the first byte of 32, 64, 1000 or 100 million sequential bytes. All other follow or are stored on address + 1, +2, +3...